# How To Get UserId() Method From ASP.NET Identity Directly in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've this issue with Custom Authorization some parts of my `Views` (which i don't want to put on `PartialView`), instead I am using `If` statement like below:

```
@if (item.CurrentComment.Id == Guid.Parse(ViewBag.UserId) || repository.IsUserInRoles(Guid.Parse(ViewBag.UserId),"Manager") )
{
    <dd>
        <a href="@Url.Action("EditComment", "Ticketing",new { id = item.CurrentComment.Id, ticketId = Model.Tickets.CurrentTicket.Id })" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left">Edit</a>
    </dd>
    <dd>
        <a href="@Url.Action("RemoveComment", "Ticketing",new { id = item.CurrentComment.Id, ticketId = Model.Tickets.CurrentTicket.Id })" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left">Remove</a>
    </dd>
}
```

At the moment I get my `UserId` in my controller and pass it over with a ViewBag like below:

```
ViewBag.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

I wondered how to call the `GetUserId` method directly in a razor so that I won't send it with a ViewBag anymore. I've tried using `User.Identity.` but the Method is Unknown there, which I assume it doesn't know the extension. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*This answer and question are for ASP.NET MVC 5,**not** ASP.NET CORE*

Add the following `using` statement at the top of your view file.

`using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;`

Following this, you should be able to use
`User.Identity.GetUserId()`

Comment: I am not able to acheive this in ASP .Net Core

Comment: @AliSajjad That's because neither the question nor this answer are for ASP.NET Core. See Grigory's answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out his answer! Actually I commented so that people using .Net Core would see the comment.

Comment: Identity does not have a definition for GetUserId()

Comment: @pianocomposer as my previous comment indicates, this is for ASP.NET MVC 5 and not ASP.NET Core. See Grigory's answer.

Answer (score 12):

If somebody is looking for an ASP.NET Core solution (as I was an hour ago), there is a solution for you:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

var user = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User);
var userId = user?.Id;
```

Answer (score 9):

Just wanted to add my take as both of the above responses didn't work for me.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager

@if (project.CreatorId == userManager.GetUserId(User))
{
  //do something
}
```

I added

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager
```

to _ViewImports.cshtml because I need to use it in several views.

Comment: 100% needs the @inject

Answer (score 3):

You could also do this.
Add the following to the top of your view file

```
@using System.Security.Claims;
```

and then, use it like that

```
string userId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
```

Comment: Definitely the simplest method (in .Net Core -- I don't know if it applies to .Net Framework) if all you need is the UserId, as initially asked.

Comment: What happen if more than one users logged in?