# Accessing UserID out of SQL Database in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a db with some users stored in it. If an user logs in, I want to read out the Users Id if a button is clicked and display it. This is what I have so far:

```
@page "/UserId"

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor _HttpContext

<div>
    @UserID;
</div>

<button class="btn btn-getstarted" @onclick="UsersID">Get UserID</button>


@code {


    private UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private string UserID;

    private string UsersID()
    {
        GetId(userManager);
        return UserID;
    }

    public async void GetId(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(_HttpContext.HttpContext.User);
        UserID = user.Id;
    }

}
```

Somehow it throws me the error
`CS1503   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'EventCallback'`    which I don't understand. Also I know in this case it's not the best way to call functions over other functions, but it seemed to work best? Is there any better way to get the ID of the current User and display it?

I referred to [this link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42343592/how-to-get-userid-method-from-asp-net-identity-directly-in-razor) but it didn't worked for me. Are there any suggestions what I can do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52351876/how-to-get-user-claims-after-signin-through-signinmanager-in-asp-net-core-ident this link might be help

Comment: `@onclick="UsersID"` Please explain what this code is trying to do.

Comment: SignInManager<TUser> and UserManager<TUser> aren't supported in Razor 
  components.

IHttpContextAccessor (HttpContext> aren't supported in Razor 
  components.

Comment: @mjwills goal is to get the Users ID, if this button will be clicked. I tried a workaroud with the `@onclick="UsersID"` and the string function but it didn't work. If I insert `@onclick="GetId"`, error will be the same.

Comment: Start with this: https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-introduction-to-authentication-with-blazor/ execute the code provided and come back to ask questions. Actually, if you want to learn Blazor, you should make the web site of @chrissainty your home for the next months, and come here to ask questions. You may also use the blazor-university web site.

Comment: @enet thank you for your suggestion, I will have a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@onclick` is expecting to see a mouseclick event handler- something like

```
    private void Click(MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs)
```

The solution is either to make UsersID and event handler (aka eventcallback):

```
private void UsersID(MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs)
{
        GetId(userManager);
}
```

Or use a lambda expression - (e) sinks the click event (its the MouseEventArgs object passed by onclick) and calls your method:

```
 @onclick="(e) => UsersID()"
```

```
    private void UsersID()
    {
        GetId(userManager);
        // Not needed - return UserID;
    }
```

Note that you don't need to return anything, you've set the UserID in GetID and the mouse event will precipitate a UI render event.

Bon Voyage with Blazor

You first port of call for help and information should be the [Microsoft Documents site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-5.0)